# El Capitan Mail.app iCloud email account default email address

Tags: icloud, mail.app, macos

Just upgraded to El Capitan OS X 10.11 and my default email account is no longer ending with mac.com but is now me.com.

When I try to change this it won't let me save it within the mail.app program.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First sign that they're doing away with the old mac.com? Shame. Give it another couple of years & we'll all be only on iCloud.com...

Comment: For what it's worth, it's only a semantic difference: you'll still get all the emails sent to @mac.com.

Answer (score 1):

Wow...found an answer elsewhere.  Basically, sign out of iCloud (System Preferences --> iCloud), restart, sign in to iCloud, restart, open Mail.  Everything seemed to reset just fine, and I could save changes to the account in Mail Preferences.